# Two tunnels with same rightsubnet for StrongSWAN/OpenSWAN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, google-cloud-platform, openswan, strongswan

I'm trying to set up the ["Option 3" configuration for Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn#advanced_settings_and_configurations), with two Google Cloud VPN gateways on the left and StrongSWAN or OpenSWAN on the right:

[image]

> If you have two Peer VPN gateways and two Compute Engine VPN gateways,
>   each Compute Engine VPN gateway can have a tunnel pointing at each
>   Peer VPN gateway public IP, giving you four load balanced tunnels
>   between the VPN gateway thereby potentially increasing 4x times the
>   bandwidth.

Problem is, as far as I can tell doing this in an active/active configuration (both tunnels serving traffic) requires that both peer gateways have the same `rightsubnet`, which causes the second tunnel to barf with "route already in use":

```
Sep 14 15:44:02 test-vpn ipsec: 002 added connection description "google1"
Sep 14 15:44:02 test-vpn ipsec: 002 added connection description "google2"
Sep 14 15:44:02 test-vpn ipsec: 003 "google2": cannot route -- route already in use for "google1"
Sep 14 15:44:02 test-vpn ipsec: 025 "google2": could not route
```

Is there any way to support this config with StrongSWAN, OpenSWAN or another software VPN package?  I see [StrongSWAN](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/1/wiki/HighAvailability) has an experimental High Availability mode, but this looks fiddly and doesn't appear to be compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may noticed in option 1 and option 2 of the [increasing VPN throughput article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn#recommended_measures_to_increase_vpn_throughput), the Compute Engine VPN gateway or network automatically load balance the traffic to Peer VPN gateway(s).

For options 3, you will need to create a cluster of your VPN gateways to run load balancing for your IPsec VPN gateways.

As you mentioned this can be done using [load sharing cluster](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/1/wiki/HighAvailability#Functional-specification) feature of the StrongSwan or you can setup a load balancer (like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)) to distributes workloads from your remote network across peer VPN gateways.